# WPF Window startup location for Per-Monitor-DPI

Tags: c#, wpf, dpi

Struggling to get a WPF Window showing up on secondary screen with mixed DPI monitors. Reproducible in .NET Framework 4.8 as well as .NET Standard 2.0

**Setup:**

Primary monitor : 4K, 250%

Secondary monitor: 1080p, 100%

[image]

**Step 1:**

add a Manifest for PerMonitorV2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  
      <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
          <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
          <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        </windowsSettings>
      </application>

    </assembly>
```

**Step 2:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
      SourceInitialized += (_, __) =>
      {
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        Width = 1920;
        Height = 1050;

        Left = -1920;
        Top = 0;
      };

      InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**Result:**

MainWindow is indeed showing up on secondary screen, but with wrong Left/Top and using DPI of the Primary screen. Only Width and Height are correct.

**References:**

The only references that I found are with regards to Notepad, are written in MFC:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/10/24/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-for-desktop-applications-and-mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/#jwYiMyGKQRTHkBP7.97

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DPIAwarenessPerWindow

Discussion on GitHub (WPF workarounds)

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4127

It is saying something about SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext but it is unclear to me how to make it work in C#....

```
DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT previousDpiContext = 
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);
BOOL ret = SetWindowPlacement(hwnd, wp);
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(previousDpiContext);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to place a window at the center of a specific monitor, get the size and location of the monitor on the desktop, calculate the  desired location of the window and set it with SetWindowPlacement function.

Comment: The first paragraph explains what the goal is. Another paragraph explains what actually happens. Quote : "MainWindow is indeed showing up on secondary screen, but with wrong Left/Top and using DPI of the Primary screen. Only Width and Height are correct."

Comment: Your Step 2 code looks like trying to make the window to fill that monitor. It is your intension?

Comment: That is correct, it should fill the working area of the secondary monitor in this example, but doesn't necessarily have to be that big. A more elaborate explanation can be found in a link that I included in the original post : https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this article, I managed to work out a solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution

The idea is to set the Thread's DPI Awareness Context to UNAWARE, during the creation of the dialog.

```
    /// changes the current Thread's "ThreadDpiAwarenessContext"
    ///   restores the current Thread's "ThreadDpiAwarenessContext" when disposed
    public class ThreadDpiAwarenessContext : IDisposable
    {
    
        /// creates a Window
        ///   in the functor, the Window's Top, Left, Width and Height properties can be adjusted in DPI unaware space
        ///   i.e. these properties will be expressed in Pixels, as if every monitor has 100% zoom factor
        public static T CreateWindow<T>(Func factory) where T : Window
        {
          using (new ThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT.DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE))
          {
            return factory();
          }
        }
    
        /// changes the current Thread's "ThreadDpiAwarenessContext"
        ///   restores the current Thread's "ThreadDpiAwarenessContext" when disposed
        public ThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT contextSwitchTo)
        {
            _resetContext = SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(contextSwitchTo);
        }
    
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed && disposing)
            {
                SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(_resetContext);
            }
            _disposed = true;
         }
    
        private DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT _resetContext;
        private bool _disposed = false;
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(IntPtr dpiContext);
    
        public struct DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT
        {
    
            public static readonly DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_INVALID = IntPtr.Zero;
            public static readonly DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = new IntPtr(-1);
            public static readonly DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = new IntPtr(-2);
            public static readonly DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = new IntPtr(-3);
            public static readonly DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 = new IntPtr(-4);
    
            private DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(IntPtr value) => _value = value;
            public static implicit operator DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(IntPtr value) => new DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(value);
            public static implicit operator IntPtr(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT context) => context._value;
            public static bool operator ==(IntPtr context1, DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT context2) => AreDpiAwarenessContextsEqual(context1, context2);
            public static bool operator !=(IntPtr context1, DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT context2) => (context1 == context2) == false;
            public override bool Equals(object obj) => base.Equals(obj);
            public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool AreDpiAwarenessContextsEqual(IntPtr dpiContextA, IntPtr dpiContextB);
    
            private IntPtr _value;
    
        }
    
    }
```

to use:

```
    var window = ThreadDpiAwarenessContext.CreateWindow(
        factory: () => new MainWindow()
            {
                Top = 500,
                Left = 500
            });
          
    window.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the window to the center of any monitor. It is just a matter of calculation.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static void MoveToCenter(Window window)
    {
        if (!GetCursorPos(out POINT cursorPoint))
            return;

        IntPtr monitorHandle = MonitorFromPoint(cursorPoint, MONITOR_DEFAULTTO.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);

        MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new() { cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<MONITORINFO>() };
        if (!GetMonitorInfo(monitorHandle, ref monitorInfo))
            return;

        IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();

        if (!GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement))
            return;

        int left = monitorInfo.rcWork.left + Math.Max(0, (int)((monitorInfo.rcWork.Width - windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Width) / 2D));
        int top = monitorInfo.rcWork.top + Math.Max(0, (int)((monitorInfo.rcWork.Height - windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Height) / 2D));

        windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition = new RECT(left, top, windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Width, windowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Height);
        SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref windowPlacement);
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(POINT pt, MONITOR_DEFAULTTO dwFlags);

    private enum MONITOR_DEFAULTTO : uint
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002,
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MONITORINFO lpmi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MONITORINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public RECT rcMonitor;
        public RECT rcWork;
        public uint dwFlags;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public uint length;
        public uint flags;
        public uint showCmd;
        public POINT ptMinPosition;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public RECT rcNormalPosition;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;

        public int Width => right - left;
        public int Height => bottom - top;

        public RECT(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            left = x;
            top = y;
            right = x + width;
            bottom = y + height;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    private bool _isMoved;

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        if (!_isMoved)
        {
            _isMoved = true;
            WindowHelper.MoveToCenter(this);
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }
}
```

But I found that the title bar's DPI remains same as that of primary monitor. In general, non-client area's DPI is hard to fix. So this hack is not so practical unless the default title bar is removed.